# Quickest way to determine if a number is a prime number or not VB

Tags: vb.net, numbers, primes

I have been working on this for quite a bit now, I have a task of creating a program which calculates if a number entered by a user is prime number or not, the program calculates the time taken and displays this to the user, however I have found two method, one takes more time than the other but it produce accurate numbers, the other one calculates very quickly however it is wrong, I am hoping if someone can help me and tell me the quickest way of calculating this, here are my two codes

Code1:

```
    Dim ch As String
    ch = "y"

    While ch = "y"

        If (num Mod 2 = 0)  Then
            Console.WriteLine("Is not a prime number!")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Is a prime number!")
        End If
```

Code2:
 check = 1  'initilizing a check point to use it in the program to determine prime number

```
    Dim Value As Long
    Console.Write(vbLf & "Enter a number To check Whater it is Prime or Not :")
    Value = Long.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
    start_time = Now
    Dim ch As ULong
    ch = 0
    Dim i As ULong
    i = 2
    While (i <= Value / 2)

        If (Value Mod i = 0) Then

            ch = 1
            Exit While

        End If

        i = i + 1

    End While
    If (ch = 0) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Prime Number")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Prime Number")
    End If
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826904/how-to-check-for-prime-numbers

Comment: Your Code1 is wrong. Your Code2 computes the correct answer, but does too much work. You should stop when *i* is greater than the square root of *Value*, not when it is greater than half of *Value*, because if *n=pq* then either *p* or *q* must be less than or equal to the square root of *n*.

Comment: @user448810 is their a sample code that you have, will look at the link provided above, thank you for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a great many prime testers out there, many of them on this site.  For checking a single number I use a faster variant of your Code2 with a little extra checking.  Here is the pseudocode:

```
boolean function isPrime(num)

  //1, 0 and negatives cannot be prime.
  if (num < 2) then
    return false
  endif

  // 2 is the only even prime.
  if (num MOD 2 = 0) then
    return (num = 2)
  endif

  // Check for odd factors.
  limit <- sqrt(num)
  for (factor <- 3; factor <= limit; factor <- factor + 2) do
    if (num MOD factor = 0) then
      return false
    endif
  endfor

  // If we reach this point then the number is prime.
  return true

endfunction
```

As @user448810 said, you should use the square root of your target number as the limit of your testing loop.  You can basically halve the number of tests you do by treating even numbers separately.  Once you have taken out the even numbers, then you only have to test odd factors: 3, 5, 7, ...

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarity,